# Does swallowing wudoo water mixes with saliva during prayer invalidates the prayer?

Tags: salat, wudu, waswasa

Hi I am suffering from major waswasah, sometimes after wudoo I can still taste a bit of the water, currently I spit to my left but I dont want to keep doing that everytime I pray. Whats the ruling on this? I couldnt find anything. Thank you

Comment: Why can't you just swallow it? Why do you think it would invalidate your prayer?

Comment: because its water, if i swallow it wouldnt it be considered as me drinking?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually sunnah to spit on the left in order to get rid of any whispering that is from the devil. Continuation of a hadith:

> Muslim (2203) from ‘Uthmaan ibn Abi’l-‘Aas (may Allah be pleased with
> him), according to which he came to the Prophet (blessings and peace
> of Allah be upon him) and said: O Messenger of Allaah, the shaytaan
> interferes between me and my prayer and my recitation, and he makes me
> confused. The Messenger of Allaah (blessings and peace of Allah be
> upon him) said: “That is a devil called Khinzab. If you feel that,
> then seek refuge with Allaah from him and spit dryly to your left
> three times.” He said: I did that and Allaah took him away from me..

You can seek protection from Allah and the devil by spitting to your left; in fact, doing so makes it more complete and perfect.

It is advised not to spit when in congregation because the person next to you can become agitated.

Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

> Someone may ask: If a man is praying in congregation, how can he spit
> dryly to his left? The answer is: If he is the last one on the left,
> he can spit dryly to his left in any place other than the mosque.
> Otherwise, he may spit dryly to his left into his garment or his
> ghutrah (head cover) or a handkerchief. If that is not possible, it is
> sufficient to turn to his left and say: A‘oodhu Billaahi min
> al-Shaytaan il-Rajeem (I seek refuge with Allah from the accursed
> Shaytaan). End quote. Fataawa Noor ‘ala al-Darb (12/155)

Consequently, according to the hadiths I've cited, there is no harm in spitting to your left. If you prefer not to do so, you can seek protection from Allah against the Shaitan instead, and that is sufficient.